# Checking ifstream, doesn't work after an error?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I've attached my code below.  If I remove the if statement to check if the file is opened, this sequence will work.  Why won't it work with the if statement?  Also, it works as written below if I supply the correct file name the first time.  It only hangs up if I enter an incorrect file name first.

Thanks for the help!

```
ifstream inputFile(fileName.c_str());

if(!inputFile)
{
    cout << "Unable to locate input file, please ensure it is in the working directory"
         << endl;
    cout << "Enter the name of your input file (ex. input.txt):  ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;

    ifstream inputFile(fileName.c_str());
}
else
{
    cout << "Input file opened successfully!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: If the user mistypes the file name, I would like to allow them to reenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show is perfectly legal, so I suppose that you use `inputFile` after this "bad filename" logic:

```
ifstream inputFile(fileName.c_str());

if(!inputFile)
{
    cout << "Unable to locate input file, please ensure it is in the working directory"
         << endl;
    cout << "Enter the name of your input file (ex. input.txt):  ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;

    ifstream inputFile(fileName.c_str());
}
else
{
    cout << "Input file opened successfully!" << endl;
}
// USING inputFile here
```

The problem with that is, that you still have the original `inputFile` here. The `inputFile` inside of the `if` statement is a *new* `std::ifstream`. It may be easier to see if you use a different name:

```
ifstream inputFile(fileName.c_str());

if(!inputFile)
{
    cout << "Unable to locate input file, please ensure it is in the working directory"
         << endl;
    cout << "Enter the name of your input file (ex. input.txt):  ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;

    ifstream differentInputFile(fileName.c_str()); //HERE
}
else
{
    cout << "Input file opened successfully!" << endl;
}
```

The correct way to close the bad file and reopen with the correct file name is:

```
inputFile.close();
inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());
```

The complete code then becomes

```
ifstream inputFile(fileName.c_str());

if(!inputFile)
{
    cout << "Unable to locate input file, please ensure it is in the working directory"
         << endl;
    cout << "Enter the name of your input file (ex. input.txt):  ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;

    inputFile.close();
    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());
}
else
{
    cout << "Input file opened successfully!" << endl;
}
```

It's also advisable to enable *warnings*. My recommendation is to use `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic -Wfatal-errors` (that's for gcc and clang).

Comment: Since the filestream was never opened, it makes more sense to `.clear()` it than to `.close()` it.

Comment: @MooingDuck `ifstream inputFile(fileName.c_str());`  opens the stream, doesn't it? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream

Comment: Thank you!  Sometimes it's the little things.

Comment: @stefan: It _attempts_ to open the stream.  If it fails, the `failbit` is set.  If the `failbit` is set, then `if(!inputFile)` evaluates to `true`, causing it to enter the block.